# Binding models inside controller actions in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, lazy-loading

Normally I load model inside classes like this:

```
public $uses = array('Table1', 'Table2', 'Table3');
```

But some of my models are only used by 2-3 actions. So I don't want to load that model for other actions. So I need to declare "table1" controller wide. And load "table2" and "table3" when I need them inside controller. Is it possible? I couldn't find inside cookbook.

Something like this:

```
class myController extends Controller {
 public $uses = array('Table1');

 public function myaction() {
  $uses = array('Table2','Table3');
 ....
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP uses lazy loading since v2.x, i.e. if you specify a model in the `$uses` array it is only loaded when it is really used, so it's fine to use your first snippet.

But if necessary you can also use the `loadModel()` method to load a model in a single action:

```
public function myaction() {
    $this->loadModel('ModelName');
    $this->ModelName->doSomething();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any controller method you can import models when required:

```
App::Import('Model', 'YourModel');

$foo = new YourModel();
```

Now you can call methods by referencing from the model Variable e.g.

```
$foo->myMethod()
```

Instead of:

```
$this->Model->myMethod();
```